# How to rename a file using java.io packages?

Tags: java, file-io

How to rename a file using `java.io` packages?

Comment: Mate next time you have a question, show some initiative and perhaps guess what makes sense as a possible class that might have the operation and then try reading the documentation. THinking, reading and trying after some thought is half the battle when one starts or is attempting to solve a problem.

Answer (score 8):

```
File oldfile = new File(old_name);
File newfile = new File(new_name);
boolean Rename = oldfile.renameTo(newfile);
```

The boolean `Rename` will be true if it successfully renamed the oldfile.

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException
    public class Rename {
      public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        // Construct the file object. Does NOT create a file on disk!
        File f = new File("Rename.java~"); // backup of this source file.

        // Rename the backup file to "junk.dat"
        // Renaming requires a File object for the target.
        f.renameTo(new File("junk.dat"));
      }
    }
```

Reference: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/RenameafileinJava.htm

Answer (score 3):

Use the `java.io.File`'s `renameTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, as of Java 7 and later, the preferred answer for this should probably be to use [`java.nio.file.Files#move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

`java.nio.file.Files.move(oldPath, newPath, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)`

The reason why one would prefer this approach is because of this documented behavior in [`java.io.File#renameTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-):

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a
>   file in a platform independent manner.

When using `java.nio.file.Files#move`, one can specify [standard `CopyOption` parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html) that indicate more nuanced behavior (e.g., what you want to happen if the file already exists, whether it must be done atomically, etc.)