# Save an exisiting file with new name

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to save an exisiting excel with a new name. but the contents should be same. It should perform the save as property for any any excel. please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using java.io packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080295/how-to-rename-a-file-using-java-io-packages)

Answer (score 1):

contents **rename** and **save as**

Quoting [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080330/1897935)

```
File oldfile = new File(old_name);
File newfile = new File(new_name);
boolean rename = oldfile.renameTo(newfile);
```

[API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

> Returns true if and only if the renaming succeeded; false otherwise

Note : Constructing the file object does NOT create a file on disk!

---

**UPDATES :** since @prasanth said question is about *save as* feature I am adding that part

For **save as feature**

reference from [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520305/java-io-to-copy-one-file-to-another)

```
    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(file1).getChannel();   
    FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(file2).getChannel();   
    dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
// also close FileChannel  objects
```

Comment: He asked about 'Save As' not 'Rename' option.

Comment: "save an exisiting excel with a new name" means "RENAME" , Am I still wrong ?? Ill still add that code for 'save as'

Comment: Save As - Save the file with the new name. Note old file still exists.  Rename - Rename the file name

Comment: @prasanth- thnx a lot prasanth for ur help. its done.