# Java Rename Problem with normale Files. With i want to rename given name to a new filename

Tags: java, rename

I use this jave code to rename the one file
from

"C:\Users\mkretsch\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\_Business\2019\Schulung\Java\Oracle\test11.csv
to
"C:\Users\mkretsch\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\_Business\2019\Schulung\Java\Oracle\test12.csv

hello_Muenchen mu = new hello_Muenchen();

```
     mu.RenameFile("C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\\_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test11.csv,"
                 , "C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\\_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test12.csv");
```

With this Java code i want to rename file_name to new_filename

```
static void RenameFile( String file_name, String new_filename ){  
    try  
    {         
        File f= new File(file_name);           //file to be renamed
        File f_new= new File(new_filename);           //file to be delete  

        if(f.renameTo(f_new))                      //returns Boolean value  
        {  
            System.out.println(f_new.getName() + " renamed");   //getting and printing the file name  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            System.out.println("failed for " + file_name + new_filename );  
        }  
    }  
        catch(Exception e)  
    {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }   

}
```

But my code fails. I always get the
message failed for 
C:\Users\mkretsch\OneDrive - Sopra Steria_Business\2019\Schulung\Java\Oracle\test11.csv,C:\Users\mkretsch\OneDrive - Sopra Steria_Business\2019\Schulung\Java\Oracle\test12.csv

Comment: What is the code for `renameTo`?

Comment: Did you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080295/how-to-rename-a-file-using-java-io-packages?

Comment: Also it looks like there is an extra comma in the first filename at the end

Comment: side note: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) because it is a more modern way to perform operations on the file system.

The following example renames the given file (as `java.nio.Path`) or throws an `Exception` (e.g. if the source file does not exist or is write protected):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path source = Paths.get(
            "C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test11.csv");
    Path target = Paths.get(
            "C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test12.csv");

    try {
        Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Didn't work...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The reason for your code not working is the trailing comma in the source file, most likely...**

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems okay, but From the file names:

```
 mu.RenameFile("C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\\_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test11.csv,"
                 , "C:\\Users\\mkretsch\\OneDrive - Sopra Steria\\_Business\\2019\\Schulung\\Java\\Oracle\\test12.csv");
```

**"C:\...\test11.csv,"** look there is an extra comma in the file name. That's why that file was not renaming.

Also check if the user has the write permission on that folder.